# Change the standard path of images in TinyMCE, where can I find the init of this editor?

Tags: tinymce

I know I can change the paths of tinyMCE to add a subdomain, see here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577520/change-default-image-path-in-tinymce

Only problem now is where can I find this init from the TinyMCE? I tried to find it but I cannot seem to find it. I'm working normally with JCE but I have to make sure the new image path works with TinyMCE, so I can hopefully change it for JCE as well, as it seems to be based on TinyMCE.

If someone could help me out, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Upload path can be configured in Editor - TinyMCE plugin configuration by setting `Images Directory` option. Upload path in TinyMCE is relative to `Path to Images Folder` option set in Media Manager.

Comment: No, it's not about the upload path. I only want to change the url of the iamges. I can do that with https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#image_prepend_url or https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/url-handling/ else I can use a script, but I need to know where the init happens so I can change it accordingly